# Program an Atmel Chip (AT90CAN128) via CAN Using AVRDUDE

Tags: microcontroller, avr, atmel, avrdude

Can AVRDUDE be used to program the AT90CAN128 micro controller via Controller Area Network (CAN)? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use AVRdude for that - It doesn't know how to handle the CAN bus. And in order to do so, it would need to reserve CAN bus message IDs which it obviously cannot.

As the AT90CAN128 does have self-programming capabilities, you may be able to write something using your own messaging on CAN that updates the Flash on the AVR.